# Android intent send email: Showing duplicate values in the Email TO field

Tags: android, email, android-intent, sendto

I am trying to send email programmatically. I am taking the input from a editText box and putting them into an array so they can be displayed in the TO field. But, it shows duplicate values and I have to click on one of them to make it a valid email address.
 How can I only display single value of the email address?

Below is the screenshot:

[Email_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apwer.png)

Below is the code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
             intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {recipient});
```

Appreciate your assistance in advance.

Comment: what about `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);`

Comment: Can you post the "recipient" array

Comment: show your `new String[] {recipient}`

Comment: problem is your `recipient` .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have already tried using new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); but it didn't help.  The recipient is an input from the EditText field that I am placing in an array list     String recipient = stringBuffer1.toString(); . Please let me know if you need further information

Comment: I am saving the recipient information in a internal storage file and then fetching it from there to show up in the email Send To field